# How to draw an irregular/hand-drawn line using svg/canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, svg, line

I want to draw a vertical line that is resizable (based on the page content), but that appears to be hand drawn, rather than straight.

I'm currently thinking of using SVG or Canvas to achieve this. The line will run down the side of my webpage, hence needs to be scalable between the top and bottom of the container. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sounds tricky. Are you sure you can't use a repeat-y background image?

Comment: Just repeating the y will mean that there will be points at which the line doesn't line up unless you land on the end of the pattern.

Comment: Well, this was just drawn with a trackpad, but I was able to make it work with the Shear tool in GIMP: http://jsfiddle.net/nkorth/K6r3u/embedded/result/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So you want to draw a line with jitter?

Try drawing a bunch of successive Bezier curves, with all of the Y-axis point parts equally spaced, and randomize the x values by some amount.

Here's an example to get you started:

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

function addJitteryBezier(fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
 var diffx = tox - fromx;
 var diffy = toy - fromy;
 
 var neg = Math.random()*diffy/5; // so the x value can go positive or negative from the typical
    
    
 ctx.bezierCurveTo(
 -neg + fromx + 2*(Math.random()*diffy/8), fromy + .3*diffy,
 -neg + fromx + 2*(Math.random()*diffy/8), fromy + .6*diffy,
 tox, toy
 );   
}

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,0);

var i = 0;
while (i < 500) {
    addJitteryBezier(50, i, 50, i+50);
    i+=  50;
}

ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GfGVE/9/

Comment: Exactly what I was just starting to try, but I haven't coded Canvas for a while.

Comment: Perfect example Simon. Thanks very much. I also found http://29a.ch/2010/2/10/hand-drawn-lines-algorithm-javascript-canvas-html5 which was ok. The only problem is that where the lines sometimes meet the curves form a peak.

Comment: Yeah, there are ways around that... If the LAST control point of a curve has some really negative X value, you will want the FIRST control point of the next curve to have a positive value. So you could do some additional checking and make sure that the first control point of the 2nd curve is always the opposite sign. If that sounds confusing, I can amend my example to show

Comment: Out of interest, if I wanted to animate the drawing of this line, I'm assuming I'd need setInterval on the while()? Is that correct?

Comment: Well, there are several ways you could animate but, but in my opinion the best way would be to do the following: First draw the whole line once to a canvas in memory. Then draw that canvas, little by little, onto the real canvas. Here is an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/GfGVE/28/

Comment: This is so creative