# How to add an Animated curly border using css

Tags: html, css, animation

Well I have some text which I wish to wrap with animated curly lines as border. Just like the one we see in animated videos with blockquote and text wrapped in borders which keep on shaking adding an awesome effect to the text. So I want to do the same on some text in html using css. 
[image: yellow color animated border which keeps shaking]

Is there a way I can do this ? Which in the example is the yellow curly animated border which keeps shaking (ignore the turquoise background) with the help of css and animated transitions or anything similar.

I know one way is using an animated image in the background but I have no idea on how to build an animated image like that besides that they are not feasible with the amount of text that gets wrapped inside.

Comment: This can be achieved with JavaScript libraries like Raphael.js and Handdrawn.js, I'm not sure how feasible this would be in CSS, but you'd probably just use `border-image` to achieve it. [Here is an example](http://codepen.io/jjelizondo/pen/imDzk) (not my work).

Comment: Actually there's a good answer for this already on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6373008/2756409

Comment: Hmm HTML5 canvas element seems to be a great solution ! :) Thanks @TylerH

Comment: I was curious to see how that example would look with a simple animation. http://jsfiddle.net/n4g3g/

Comment: OMG ! Thats exactly how I imagined it . Thank you so much @Tank You are awesome! ♥