# HTML5 Canvas code: need help changing hand-drawn vertical line to horizontal

Tags: html, canvas

This is in reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6373008/1247334.

Overview: attempting to utilize referenced HTML5 Canvas code to make both a vertical, and separately, a horizontal line on my page that fills the height and width (respectively) of its container.

Yes, would normally just use CSS borders, but wanting the "hand drawn" look for these lines. Yes, could just use graphics, but just trying something new and seeing if it'd be smaller in filesize than the graphical options.

From the referenced link above, Simon's code from his fiddle #16 is what I used as my starting point:

- Simon's code @ `jsfiddle.net/GfGVE/16`
- my version @ `codepen.io/syberknight/pen/gpgxqX`

...knowing nothing of Canvas code until this, as you can see I've been able to figure out a few things - most notably, a way to have the line extend (draw, not stretch) to 100% of it's **container (not window).

But I've become stuck in trying to make this horizontal" rather than vertical (actually need both).

I've tried many iterations of reversing the "x" & "y" options throughout, but so far have only ended up with a mess at `codepen.io/syberknight/pen/BNpwKO`

Comment: whoever downvoted me - kindly comment as to why please!

Comment: I've downvoted as well, with apologies. Your questions seem to use excessive bold/italics, all-lower-case writing, use ampersand instead of "and", and here you've side-stepped the requirement to add code to questions by dropping the `http://` prefix to JS Fiddle and Codepen links. If you can repair this question by adding in the code you're referring to (using the code formatting tools) I'll withdraw the downvote. Remember we like to leave questions here in a useful state for future readers. Thanks, and hope the feedback helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use canvas transformations to turn your vertical line into a horizontal line.**

`context.translate` will reposition the [0,0] origin of the canvas.

`context.rotate` will rotate any new drawings by a specified angle.

**Here is example code and a Demo:**

[image]

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var lastControl = 0;

function addJitteryBezier(fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
  var diffx = tox - fromx;
  var diffy = toy - fromy;

  var neg = Math.random()*diffy/5; // so the x value can go positive or negative from the typical


  var cp1x = -neg + fromx + 2*(Math.random()*diffy/8);
  var cp2x = -neg + fromx + 2*(Math.random()*diffy/8);

  if (lastControl < fromx) { // if last control was negative, make this one positive
    cp1x = fromx + fromx - cp1x;
  } else {
    cp1x = fromx - (cp1x - fromx);
  }
  lastControl = cp2x;

  ctx.bezierCurveTo(
    cp1x, fromy + .3*diffy,
    cp2x, fromy + .6*diffy,
    tox, toy
  );  
}

// save the untranslated and unrotated context state
ctx.save();

// use translate to push the canvas origin down by 100px
ctx.translate(0,100);

// rotate all new drawings by -90 degrees
ctx.rotate(-Math.PI/2);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,0);

var i = 0;
while (i < 500) {
  addJitteryBezier(50, i, 50, i+50);
  i+=  50;
}

ctx.stroke();

// restore the context state to its untranslated and unrotated state
ctx.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width=500 height=500></canvas>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! i'm assuming the "save" & "restore" lines aren't necessary since i was able to comment them out & it still work. so i'm not sure what they'd be needed for. i was able to get my 100% width stuff in there successfully too @ http://codepen.io/syberknight/pen/BNpwKO

Comment: You're welcome. The .save & .restore become necessary as you draw additional things on the canvas. Without .save / .restore your new drawings will become horizontal. Good luck with your project!